# How do I pass a defined in a concept reference to a template function?

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
template<std::same_as<int&> T>
void f(T value) {}
```

Compiler gives me an error that I don't have a function with these arguments `f(int)` if I call it like this:

```
void g() {
    int a;
    int& b = a;
    f(b);
}
```

Why does the compiler assume that I use a regular type and not a reference and is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a forwarding reference, the template type is never deduced as a reference type.  Instead, it gets the type the reference refers to.  In this case that means `T` is deduced as an `int` and that does not match `int&`.  Instead you can use

```
template<std::same_as<int> T>
void f(T& value) {}
```

Which forces `T` to be an `int`, and then `T&` makes `value` a reference to the object passed to the function.